# Insert com objetos compostos

Tags: c#, wcf, nhibernate

recebo este json

```
 {
  "Name": "Teste",
  "ExpirationDate": "/Date(1515703416000-0200)/",
  "Program": { 
    "Id": 1
  },
  "Resource":{
    "Id": 1
  },
    "InsertDate": "/Date(1515703416000-0200)/",
    "InsertUserId": 8,
    "LastUpdateDate": null,
    "LastUpdateUserId": null

}
```

e meu servico esta assim:

```
  public string CreateAbility(CallDomain.Ability ability)
    {

        if (ReferenceEquals(ability, null))
        {
            throw new WcfException(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ErrorMessage.Resource.EMPTY);
        }
        else if(!(ability.Program?.Id > 0))
        {
            throw new WcfException(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ErrorMessage.Program.ID_REQUIRED);
        }
        else if (!(ability.Resource?.Id > 0))
        {
            throw new WcfException(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ErrorMessage.Resource.ID_REQUIRED);
        }

        var repository = new AbilityRepository(_user.Id);
        ability.IsActive = true;

        var repResource = new ResourceRepository(_user.Id);
        var dbResource = repResource.Get(ability.Resource.Id);

        var repProgram = new ProgramRepository(_user.Id);
        var dbProgam = repProgram.Get(ability.Program.Id);

        ability.Resource = dbResource;
        ability.Program = dbProgam;
        _ability = repository.Create(ability);
        return CustomJsonSerializer.Serialize(_ability);

    }
```

Eu preciso realmente buscar no banco de dados os meus `Program` e `Resource`, antes de inserir o `ability` ?

O `Resource` e o `Program` já irão existir no BD no momento em que eu estou inserindo o objeto `ability`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

mapeamento Ability

```
 <class name="Ability" table="Ability">
    <id name="Id" column="Id">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <property name="Name" column="Name" />
    <property name="IsActive" column="IsActive" />
    <property name="ExpirationDate" column="ExpirationDate" />
    <property name="InsertDate" column="InsertDate" />
    <property name="InsertUserId" column="InsertUserId" />
    <property name="LastUpdateDate" column="LastUpdateDate" />
    <property name="LastUpdateUserId" column="LastUpdateUserId" />

    <many-to-one name="Program" column="ProgramId" fetch="join" />

    <many-to-one name="Resource" column="ResourceId" fetch="join" />


  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

mapeamento program

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                    assembly="BipDomain"
                    namespace="BipDomain.Models.ProgramDomain">

  <class name="Program" table="Program">
    <id name="Id" column="Id">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>

    <property name="Name" column="Name" />
    <property name="IsActive" column="IsActive" />
    <property name="InsertDate" column="InsertDate" />
    <property name="InsertUserId" column="InsertUserId" />
    <property name="LastUpdateDate" column="LastUpdateDate" />
    <property name="LastUpdateUserId" column="LastUpdateUserId" />


    <bag name="Abilities" cascade="All">
      <key column="ProgramId" />
      <one-to-many class="BipDomain.Models.CallDomain.Ability"  />
    </bag>



  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

mapeamento resource

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                    assembly="BipDomain"
                    namespace="BipDomain.Models.ProgramDomain">

  <class name="Resource" table="Resource">
    <id name="Id" column="Id">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>

    <property name="Name" column="Name" />
    <property name="IsActive" column="IsActive" />
    <property name="InsertDate" column="InsertDate" />
    <property name="InsertUserId" column="InsertUserId" />
    <property name="LastUpdateDate" column="LastUpdateDate" />
    <property name="LastUpdateUserId" column="LastUpdateUserId" />

    <bag name="Abilities" cascade="All" >
      <key column ="ResourceId" />
      <one-to-many class="BipDomain.Models.CallDomain.Ability"/>
    </bag>


  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Provavelmente não, apenas as chaves estrangeiras é suficiente para que o Entity compreender que os registros já existem. Porém, é difícil saber sem analisar o seu mapeamento/repositório.

Comment: Por quê você não faz o teste? Comentá as 2 linhas e tenta inserir

Comment: Adicionei o mapeamento só um detalhe, não esta com Entity e sim com NHibernate